# iOS - Swift : Expand user profile picture in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, popup, expand

I am trying to obtain an animation from `UITableViewCell` (holding information about user, with profile picture ), by expanding user's profile picture from this:

[image]

**////////////////

to this

///////////////**

[image]
    enter code here

It works, but the problem is that the animation somehow starts from the corner of the screen, not from the rounded image in `UITableViewCell`.

```
func handlePictureTap(conversationTableCell: ConversationTableCell) {
    guard let cellIndexPath = self.conversationsTableView.indexPath(for: conversationTableCell) else { return }

    transitionDelegate.openingFrame = self.frameForCellAtIndexPath(cellIndexPath)

    let userProfileViewController = UserViewController(nibName: "UserViewController", bundle: nil)
    userProfileViewController.recentProfileProtocol = self
    userProfileViewController.transitioningDelegate = transitionDelegate
    userProfileViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    userProfileViewController.userProfileName = conversationTableCell.conversationName.text!
    userProfileViewController.userProfileImage = conversationTableCell.conversationPicture.image

    self.present(navEditorViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And the function for frameForCellAtIndexPath.

```
func frameForCellAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGRect {
    let cell = self.conversationsTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ConversationTableCell

    let profileImageFrame = cell.conversationPicture.frame

    return profileImageFrame
}
```

I cannot manage to obtain the correct frame for it, related to entire screen, in order for my animation to start from cell's profile picture.

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Thanks for the edit Nitish. Wasn't able to add the pictures directly, due to low score :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting the animation from the frame of the image which is relative to the table view cell coordinate system where it is placed in the upper left.

To determine the current position of the cell relative to the table view you can use something like this:

```
let rect = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
```

In case you need the rect relative to another view you can use UIViews

```
convert(_ rect: NSRect, from view: NSView?) -> NSRect
```

**Update**

To apply that to your specific case assuming that you need the openingRect in screen coordinates you could do something like:

```
let cellOrigin = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath).origin

let rectRelativeToTable = CGRect(x: imageFrame.origin.x + cellOrigin.x,
                                 y: imageFrame.origin.y + cellOrigin.y,
                                 width: imageFrame.size.width,
                                 height: imageFrame.size.height)

let openingRect = tableView.convert(rectRelativeToTable, to: nil)
```

Comment: But with your approach, the animation starts from center of cell, which is not what I intend.

Comment: Life saver. Just did that, forgot about cellOrigin. Thank you, sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else is looking for the same animation, here are transition classes:
**DismissalAnimator**

```
import UIKit

class DismissalAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
var openingFrame: CGRect?


func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
    return 0.6
}


func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from)!
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

    let animationDuration = self .transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)

    let snapshotView = fromViewController.view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
    containerView.addSubview(snapshotView!)

    fromViewController.view.alpha = 0.0

    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: animationDuration,
        animations: { () -> Void in
            snapshotView!.frame = self.openingFrame!
            snapshotView!.alpha = 0.0
    },
        completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            snapshotView!.removeFromSuperview()

            fromViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()

            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
    })
  }  

}
```

**PresentationAnimator**

```
import UIKit

class PresentationAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
var openingFrame: CGRect?


func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
    return 0.6
}


func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from)!
    let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)!
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

    let animationDuration = self.transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)

    containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)

    let snapshotView = toViewController.view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
    snapshotView!.frame = openingFrame!

    toViewController.view.alpha = 0.0
    snapshotView!.alpha = 0

    containerView.addSubview(snapshotView!)

    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: animationDuration,
        delay: 0.0,
        usingSpringWithDamping: 2.0,
        initialSpringVelocity: 5.0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut,
        animations: { () -> Void in
            snapshotView!.frame = fromViewController.view.frame
            snapshotView!.alpha = 1
    },
        completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            snapshotView!.removeFromSuperview()

            toViewController.view.alpha = 1.0

            transitionContext.completeTransition(finished)
    })
  }
}
```

**TransitioningDelegate**

```
import UIKit

class TransitioningDelegate: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
var openingFrame: CGRect?


func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    let presentationAnimator = PresentationAnimator()
    presentationAnimator.openingFrame = openingFrame

    return presentationAnimator
}


func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    let dismissAnimator = DismissalAnimator()
    dismissAnimator.openingFrame = openingFrame!

    return dismissAnimator
   }
}
```

- the code above, provided by @Stephan Schlecht will get you the same animation.